# How to play YouTube videos using WPF MediaKit?

Tags: c#, wpf, youtube, stream, wpf-mediakit

I'm trying to play YouTube streams in my WPF program using WPF MediaKit's MediaUriElement.
I've noticed that the url should be something like this:

Source="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyNqNJUAuh4&hd=1?ext=.3gpp"

So I extract the extension from the YouTubeInfo and construct such a string.

However the MediaUriElement doesn't cooparate with that...
(I have the K-Lite Codec Pack installed)

Does someone know how it can be done?

Idan

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142615/Custom-Media-Player-in-WPF-Part

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/VideoWPF04082007164613PM/VideoWPF.aspx

Comment: Thanks but I would like to use WPFMediaKit...

Answer (score 0):

[WPF-MediaKit](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit) itself cannot play any media, it's the problem of the codecs used. E.g. can MPC-HC player (bundled with the K-Lite codecs) play that URL/file? If not, then the WPF-MediaKit cannot play it, too.